# Converting global object location to local location in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to use `ray_cast()` in Blender Python and I found that you need the local location of every object instead of the global location.

I started searching on the web and people said you have to do it this way:

```
localPos = object.matrix_world_inverted() * target.location
```

But this gives me the same coordinates as the global location...

Comment: Except that the code should read `.inverted()` with a period, it works when I try it. Is `object` not at the origin ?

Comment: I'll try with the '.'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Converting global coordinates of object B
 to local coordinates of object A**

The global coordinate of object A (`obj_a`)

```
global_coord = obj_a.matrix_world.translation
```

To convert from a global coordinate to the local space of object A

```
local_coord = obj_a.matrix_world.inverted() * global_coord
```

Using the global coordinate of object A in the local coordinate equation above yeilds `Matrix.Identity().translation` ,  *since multiplying a matrix by its inverse results in the identity matrix*, which has a translation component of `(0, 9, 0)` aka the origin of our local coordinate system.

Putting it altogether in a test script.  Object A is represented by the context object   All #other selected objects are  iterated as object B.

```
import bpy
# context for test code
from bpy import context

selected_obs = context.selected_objects
ob_a = context.object
#selected_obs.remove(ob_a) # will be at local origin
mwi = ob_a.matrix_world.inverted()
print("local coordinates of", ob_a.name)
for ob_b in selected_obs:
    local_pos = mwi * ob_b.matrix_world.translation
    print(ob_b.name, local_pos)
```

Result of running on Default Scene, with cube then camera as active object

```
local coordinates of Cube
Cube <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)>
Lamp <Vector (4.0762, 1.0055, 5.9039)>
Camera <Vector (7.4811, -6.5076, 5.3437)>

local coordinates of Camera
Cube <Vector (-0.3382, -0.3767, -11.2523)>
Lamp <Vector (3.1254, 3.9298, -6.5683)>
Camera <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, -0.0000)>
```

Global locs from console

```
>>> for o in C.scene.objects:
...     o.name, o.matrix_world.translation
...     
('Cube', Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0)))
('Lamp', Vector((4.076245307922363, 1.0054539442062378, 5.903861999511719)))
('Camera', Vector((7.481131553649902, -6.5076398849487305, 5.34366512298584)))

>>>
```

Comment: I'd like to mention here that the matrix multiplication operator in Blender 2.8 is now @ instead of *

Comment: If you could add that comment to all answers pre 2.8 using * instead of @ that would be great.

Comment: If you have applied transformations to an object, it's `matrix_world` is `Matrix(((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))` which is useless (2.8x)

Comment: Matrix.Identity(4).translation